# ¿Cómo puedo poner una excepción en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

quería saber si podéis ayudarme con la excepción.
Se como hacerlo en java, pero no sé como ponerlo en python.

```
int op;
    op =0;
    try{
        op = input.nextInt();
    }catch(InputMismatchException ime){
        System.out.println("No se admiten letras.\nVuelva a intentarlo de nuevo.");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
```

Quisiera saber que tipo de excepción sería en python. Me refiero, a como poner esta misma excepción en python. 
(se que se usa try, except, pero no que nombre tendría que poner en except o si no hace falta poner un nombre.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: porque no agregas tu codigo python para explicarlo, recuerda que tu pregunta la pueden ver otros usuarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera sencilla de conseguir eso, es hacerlo de esta manera:

**Código:**

```
try:
  x = int(input("Dame un numero: "))
except ValueError:
  print("Eso no es un número, prueba otra vez...")
```

Se pide un numero por teclado, si ese dato capturado es numérico, todo bien, en cambio si se introduce un carácter, muestra el mensaje de la excepción.